# Call to undefined method mysqli::data_seek()

Tags: php, mysqli, xampp

I am currently transitioning my website from MySQL to MySQLi and I have run into an issue. I have been searching for hours but none of the results that I find have been able to help me. In my connect.php file I have the following code:

```
<?php

connect_db();

function connect_db() {
    $connect_error = 'Sorry, we are experiencing connection issues.';
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db') or die($connect_error);

}

function mysqli_result($res, $row, $field=0) {
    $res->data_seek($row);
    $datarow = $res->fetch_array();
    return $datarow[$field];
}

?>
```

*mysqli_result()* gets called in *login.php* and *register.php*.

Whenever I try to log in or register, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli::data_seek() in C:\xampp\htdocs\core\database\connect.php on line 10

line 10 contains *$res->data_seek($row);*

Here are the extensions in my *php.ini* file:

```
extension=php_bz2.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
;extension=php_gmp.dll
;extension=php_intl.dll
;extension=php_imap.dll
;extension=php_interbase.dll
;extension=php_ldap.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
;extension=php_oci8_12c.dll
;extension=php_openssl.dll
;extension=php_pdo_firebird.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
;extension=php_pdo_oci.dll
;extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
;extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
;extension=php_pgsql.dll
;extension=php_shmop.dll
```

EDIT:

This is where *mysqli_result* is used:

```
function user_count() {
    $mysqli = connect_db();
    $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `active` = 1");
    return mysqli_result($mysqli, $query, 0);
}
```

Comment: Did you check if `$res` is a valid Mysqli result object ? how and where are you calling your mysqli_result() ?

Comment: What is `$res` I would guess its NOT a MYSQLI_Statement object or a MYSQLI_Result object Show us how you create `$res`

Comment: @Vincent Sorry, I probably should of remembered that. I will edit question and add at the bottom.

Comment: Erm... You added a return to your `connect_db()` function?? Which was the answer I gave!! Now its a different questions!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Actually this issue could be related to the fact that you do not return a value from `connect_db()`

Without returning the `$mysqli` variable, your connection object will be totally invisible to the rest of your script! In fact it will not even exist once this function finishes

So amend it to this

```
function connect_db() {
    $connect_error = 'Sorry, we are experiencing connection issues.';
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db') or die($connect_error);
    return $mysqli;
}
```

There is a much easier way of doing this:

```
function user_count() {
    $mysqli = connect_db();
    $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) FROM `users` WHERE `active` = 1");
    return mysqli_result($mysqli, $query, 0);
}
```

Like this, by adding an Alias i.e. a usable name to the result column

```
function user_count() {
    $mysqli = connect_db();  // ??
    $query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) as num 
                                    FROM `users` WHERE `active` = 1");
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    return row['num'];
}
```

Its also a much better idea to connect to the Database ONCE per script, not once for every access to the database as connecting is quite a time consuming operation!